# AWS Cognito, Keycloak, Auth0, Okta. additional fields on login form

Tags: amazon-cognito, keycloak, auth0, okta

i need to make an authorization using three fields. organizationId, username and password

and for this reason i would like to use one of Identity Provider services like AWS Cognito, Keycloak, Auth0, Okta.

I have one question:
is it possible to add additional fields (for example organization id) on login form, not on registration form, for any of this Identity Provider services ?

and if yes then how?

thx.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add custom attributes in Cognito, if that's what you are asking.

It's there under User Pools -> General settings -> Attributes

[image]

Comment: Can I add the customer Attribute on log in form? Not on sign up form?

Comment: If you are building your own login form, you can use it and pass the parameter to Cognito.